# Access denied or Not Found errors from Graph API while Access other users calendar in Office 365

Tags: ruby-on-rails, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-calendar

I want to access other user calendars of my organization from my admin account on Microsoft office 365. On office 365 I can search and access those calendars.
I want to Access these (other user's) calendars using Microsoft Graph API.
Here are the official documentations for accessing office 365 calendar using Graph APIs.
1. [Calendars from Users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event)
2. [Directly Access Calenders](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars)

Here is my Auth Helper class in which I am defining my permission scopes

```
module AuthHelper

  CLIENT_ID = '91e6****-****-40f7-9b46-******d1149c'
  CLIENT_SECRET = 'pftjo*******55;hwSN2-(%'

  SCOPES = [ 'openid',
             'profile',
             'User.Read',
             'Mail.Read',
             'Calendars.Read',
             'Calendars.Read.Shared' ]

  def get_login_url
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID,
                                CLIENT_SECRET,
                                :site => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
                                :authorize_url => '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
                                :token_url => '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token')

    login_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => authorize_url, :scope => SCOPES.join(' '))
  end

  def get_token_from_code(auth_code)
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID,
                                CLIENT_SECRET,
                                :site => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
                                :authorize_url => '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
                                :token_url => '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token')

    token = client.auth_code.get_token(auth_code,
                                   :redirect_uri => authorize_url,
                                   :scope => SCOPES.join(' '))
  end
```

Trying postman:

*https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users* query along with headers showing me all users but

*GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars* query showing me 404 Not Found error.

In short, I can access other user's calendar from search bar of my office365 application but can not access using

[any of these methods](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only apps that run outside of a user context (like a service/daemon app) can access every calendar in the organization.  [Getting access tokens for apps that run without the presence of a signed-in user is a bit different](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) and you'll need to go through the admin consent flow to give your app access to everyone's calendar. I just tested this and `Calendars.Read` is the only scope you need.

[image]

The steps are:

1. Register your app
2. Add `Calendars.Read` as an application permission
3. Grant admin consent to your app by going to a URL like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{REPLACE WITH TENANT}/adminconsent?nonce=graph&prompt=select_account&client_id={REPLACE_WITH_APP_ID}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3001&state=foobar`

Once I got an access token, the rest call to access another users calendar was exactly what you posted in the question:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user-id]/calendars`

Once you have a calendar ID you can view their calendar events at:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user-id]/calendars/[calendar-id]/events`

I encourage you to see our calendar samples in the [Graph explorer](http://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

[image]

Comment: I am constantly getting 404 while requesting anything with calendar. But I can access user, groups etc. any Suggestion ?